# The appropriate way to solve tslint-immutable functional programming principles

Tags: javascript, typescript, functional-programming, immutability

I have a cli app i'm writing that brings in command line options.

In an object if i'm checking that a directory property exists.

my old way...

```
if(!clOptions.directory)
throw error
```

[directory](https://www.npmjs.com/package/command-line-args) being a -d flag followed by a folder path

```
index.js -d /home/folder/data
```

various typeof, ternary combinations keep getting me trapped in [tslint-immutable](https://npm.taobao.org/package/tslint-immutable) violations.

consequently strict functional programming, no-expression-statement and no-if-statement have me thrown.

assume that i want to follow functional programming paradigms strictly and tslint-immutable what would be the appropriate way to:

1. validate that directory property exists on **clOptions** and is a string
2. if neither of those are true, stop execution with an error message.

Comment: What type is `clOptions`?

Comment: it is a {} provided from: https://www.npmjs.com/package/command-line-args

Comment: no-if-statement

Comment: It looks masochistic to me: JS does not provide convenient tools to comply with all those requirements.

Comment: it started to feel like that.  I was spending a lot of energy for not a lot of gain.  was hoping for some insight.

Comment: Tell the linter to STFU. The point of functional programming is not to *eliminate* side effects (which would be impossible) but to *isolate* them at the edges of your code. Command line arguments are something you can't really get around: you simply cannot control as the programmer of the utility whether or not the user passes you a valid argument.